# Form without action Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have been recently working with Ruby on Rails and have run into an issue that I can not quite figure out.  I need to create a bunch of form mockups, that do not function.  That is they should have the submit button, but it should not do anything upon being clicked.  Normally using html I would do something along the lines of

```
<form action="#">
</form>
```

Trying to convert this to use Rails form helpers, I have done the following

```
<%= form_tag "#" do %>
    <%= label_tag :username, "Username: " %>
    <%= text_field_tag :username %>
    <br />
    <%= label_tag :password, "Password: " %>
    <%= password_field_tag :password %>
    <br />
    <%= submit_tag "Login" %>
<% end %>
```

This generates a form that is similar to what I want to achieve, however when clicking the submit button it tries to access /# via post which is not the desired result.  Currently the only thing I can think of to achieve this is to set the disabled attribute of the button, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this can't be achieved with form helpers. Defining a `form_for` or a `form_tag` requires an action for the form. You can set

```
:action => "#"
```

But this will require including the action in routes -> having a controller with action for it -> rendering some page yet again.

You could manipulate the form after loading with javascript however (sust remember to set `:remote` to true - ). Or alternatively, if you insist on using the form helpers - replace the submit_tag with a `button_tag`:

```
 <%= button_tag "Login", :type => 'button'%>
```

Comment: This works, thank you.  And while both answers posted were correct, this one went into more detail as to why what I was doing did not work which is why I choose it.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
<% form_tag "#", :onSubmit => "return false" do %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried with `button_tag` instead of `submit_tag`? See [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-button_tag). Just make sure you don't use the default, or you will be right back where you started.